# Angular: update ng-include on CRUD event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a constant sidebar in my index.html file that lists projects using ng-include. When a project is created, or updated etc.. I would like the sidebar to automatically update along with it. I'm not sure which part of my code to provide, as hopefully it's a fundamental question that's easy to answer, though the solution eludes me.

Edit: feel I'm almost there, but src doesn't seem to pick up the controller property:

```
<div class="col col-md-4" data-ng-controller="ProjectsController" data-ng-include src="'{{sidebarUrl}}'"></div>
```

In my projects controller:

```
// Update existing Project
    $scope.update = function() {
        var project = $scope.project ;

        project.$update(function() {
            $location.path('projects/' + project._id);
                            $scope.$broadcast('projectUpdated');
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };

$scope.sidebarUrl = 'modules/projects/views/list-projects.client.view.html';

            $scope.$on("projectUpdated",function(event,args) {
                $scope.sidebarUrl=null;
                $scope.sidebarUrl= 'modules/projects/views/list-projects.client.view.html';
           });
```

Comment: Does the ngInclude have a controller that has a list of projects?

Comment: Trying to follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203777/angularjs-reload-ng-include-after-user-authentication-or-a-better-way-to-solve but having a hard to getting the src of the include to picked up by the controller property. Will update question.

Comment: @Chris - The issue is that the URL doesn't actually change. Angular doesn't care that you set it to `null` and then back again. If after the `$digest` loop is finished running the old value and new value are different, it won't update.

Answer (score 0):

This is where services are your friend. You should start by encapsulating your CRUD operations into a service.

```
function MyCrudService($http, ...){ ... }

angular.module('my-app')
  .service('myCrudService', MyCrudService);
```

Now, there are several ways you could implement the updating.

**Use `$rootScope` and broadcast a message** saying something has changed, and listen for that event in your sidebar controller (assuming you have one).

```
//Inside your service
function updateProject(proj){
   //Update project
   $rootScope.$broadcast('project-updated', proj);
}

//Inside your controller
function MySidebarController($scope){
   $scope.$on('project-updated', function(){ ... });
}
```

**Encapsulate the eventing logic inside your service** to avoid using `$rootScope`. Just maintain your own list of callbacks and execute them.

```
//Inside your controller
function MySidebarController(myCrudService){
   myCrudService.onProjectChanged(function(){ ... });
}
```

**Expose the shared data on your service** that can be databound to.

```
//Inside your controller
function MySidebarController($scope, myCrudService){
  $scope.projects = myCrudService.projects;
}
```

**Personally, I try to avoid `$scope` in my controllers**, but using it for eventing is OK. Still, I might write some kind of directive that would allow me to execute an expression whenever an event fired in order to avoid it.

```
<my-event-binding event='project-updated' expression='sideBar.updateProjects()' />
```

Comment: This has just gone a bit over my head... I'm very new to angular, but I'll see if I can make it work - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had the same requirement(dynamically changing menu items in an included side panel) what I did was to use a controller in the ng-include template. The template would then fetch the relevant menu items from a service and update the controller. The view had an ng-repeat directive to show all the menu items (projects in your case).

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectsCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="project in projects">
            <a ng-href="project.url">
                {{project.name}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The controller function could look something like:

```
function($scope, projectsSvc){
    $scope.projects = [];

    loadProjects();
    $scope.$on("updatedProjects", loadProjects);

    function loadProjects(){
        projectsSvc.getProjects.success(function(projects){
            $scope.projects = projects;
        });
    }
}
```

Projects are fetched from a service. When you update a project, broadcast an event that triggers a load of the projects again.
So after the new projects have been committed into the service backend, the sidebar will update accordingly.